# Link to google colab project so that students must copy of and modify

Tags: google-colaboratory, sharing

I am trying to make a link to a Google Colab project such that students must make a copy of the template and then modify for their own work.  This is possible on other google documents by modifying the link from "edit" or "view" to "copy".  This does not seem to be possible for Colab projects.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: How about Google Classroom with the "Make a copy for each student" option? https://katiesylvia.medium.com/implementing-google-colab-into-your-google-classroom-88cf22841176

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to put everything within one folder (Colab + other folders) then share it with them.